# Atmospheric Water Extraction

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

So most of you have probably heard of extracting hydrogen and oxygen from the air to make water.

In a world where water could be scarce, is this technique even feasible?

Specifically, assuming expected technological advancement to ~2100, could a portable (or even a fixed, privately-owned) device perform this function? Could a regular person 'create water out of thin air'?

Or am I being too optimistic?

Comment: Indeed all you need is a match!

Comment: return the question let it be. I was going to answer it not focusing on hydrogen, as vapor extraction was pretty valid point of the question you wrote. But basically any cryogenic device can extract water  from vapor from pretty low concentrations. Just edit it according those hydrogen extraction stuff you got from other answers and move on to main problem - how to get water, assuming it is at low concentrations in atmosphere.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts, Distilled.

Answer (score 9):

I have never heard of "extracting hydrogen and oxygen from the air to make water"; I suppose that's because there is no¹ hydrogen in the air -- Earth's gravity is too weak to retain hydrogen, and any amount of hydrogen which gets in the atmosphere will either combine with oxygen or, if it somehow manages to avoid combining with oxygen, will escape into outer space.

Hydrogen and oxygen like each other very very much and will combine at the slightest opportunity. You may have seen the famous footage of the Hindenburg... That's hydrogen combining with oxygen.

Both hydrogen and oxygen are highly reactive. Earth has free oxygen in the atmosphere because green plants produce it continuously; it is a waste product of the photosynthesis process. Without continuous replenishment all the oxygen would eventually find something to combine with. (All the animals would die first, of course.)

¹) Well, as Ayutac mentions, there is a trace amount of hydrogen in the air, about 0.5 parts per million... The driest air has 10 parts per million water vapor, with 2500 parts per million water vapor on the average.

Comment: and after that oxygen will combine with dead plants and animals and will live forever in form of CO2 )

Answer (score 2):

Hydrogen doesn't exist on its own in the atmosphere of any planet with oxygen (or probably even most planets without oxygen unless the planet is a gas giant). Hydrogen is always part of another molecule - on Earth's atmosphere this is most often in the form of water, methane, or ammonia. If hydrogen gas was present, it has such a low density that it would rise higher and higher in the atmosphere until it was on the edge of space. Then the solar wind would knock it loose from the planet.

I'm not really sure how scarce water is on your planet. If water vapor could not be condensed out of the atmosphere, and ground water could not be accessed by drilling a well, I would recommend looking for natural gas or oil deposits. Both of those produce water when burned. It is hard to imagine how fossil fuels could be produced without available water, but maybe it works on your world?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are wrong in the regard that there is no Hydrogen in the air. [There is](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/1999JD900788/abstract) (troposphere is our breathing air layer). It is just a really really small amount, about 5 * 1e-5 %. That means you would need about 2e6 liters of air to get one liter of hydrogen. The troposphere has an approximate volume of 8.15e3 m3 (you can calculate it yourself, reasonable steps are [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100914172137AAsWOEW)) that are 8.15e6 liters. In other words, you would drain all the hydrogen out of the troposphere to collect about a third liter of it. That is even less water, roughly about 200ml, according to [this source](http://www.instructables.com/answers/volume-of-water-from-a-litre-of-hydrogen/). Implying you had some way to drain it globally in the first place. For comparison, there is about [12900 km3 Water in the atmosphere](http://water.usgs.gov/edu/watercycleatmosphere.html) or 1.3 * 1e16 liters, most of it on the lower troposphere. Of course only on earth, but the site mentioned it's about 0.001% of earth water, maybe you can use that.

Fazit: Possible, but not feasable, not even in our world.

Comment: That's 0.5 parts per million...

Comment: @MolbOrg I was just going for an Estimate, assuming equal density. So my thought on concentration was in 1 liter air there's 5e-7 liter H2, hence multiplication by 2. Assuming volume concentration in the source, because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration#Volume_concentration I don't see why my approach is wrong, but I'm willing to learn :)

Comment: @MolbOrg but you are completely right about the volume. I forgot they have different densities. corrected my post (again, an estimate)

Comment: Messed with my comments to so will delete it, so you right about numbers got it(but really fractions would be better then percents). Although "8.15e3 m3 and 8.15e6 liters" looks way to low for troposphere. according to [this](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~lgrace/chem123/troposphere.htm) - "The troposphere contains 75 percent of atmosphere's mass...". wiki: "The atmosphere has a mass of about 5.15e18 kg" in fact for all atmosphere there should be a lot of hydrogen, more then for 200ml of water.

Comment: Other answers are not wrong. "no hydrogen" is reasonable approximation in this context.

Comment: @MolbOrg The troposphere is also said to contain 99% of the water of the atmosphere, which I looked for. The USGS seems to be a reliable source as well as the paper with the hydrogen estimates. It may be more hydrogen, but I guess the order of magnitude does not exceed 1e1. Still far to low to be feasible.

Comment: @Mołot That is debatable. "almost none" =/= "none", but that is nitpicking. I also emphasized "in the regard", so I guess everything is fine?

Comment: @Ayutac no no, I'm not about extraction of hydrogen from atmosphere to make some water, except situations where it is only option and some one have tooons of energy to do that and have technology to do so. I'm just about of correctness of the numbers in cases when they are used. Number are good thing, because they can show things in more defined ways, but errors happens time to times when they are used, so our goal to use them and to see errors when it is possible to see.

Comment: @AlexP - "That's 0.5 parts per million" Nope. That's 50 ppm. Actually, about 55 ppm, but who's counting?

Comment: 5E-5 % = 5E-7 = 0.5/1E6. See also [Atmosphere of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **energy**, it is orders of magnitude more efficient to purify or treat water than to manufacture it.  So what you would actually do is **recycle** all your grey water and waste and grow crops in closed chambers, so a supply of water can go around and around. You only have to replace losses, which is a tiny percentage of the total water “use”. And that will be more efficient to **transport** than to make where it is not found naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question's author meant extracting water from water vapor present in the atmosphere, this can certainly be done, but it requires a fair bit of energy to force the gas/water phase change, not to mention moving large masses of air around.

point of reference is inventor Dean Kamen's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slingshot_(water_vapor_distillation_system)

I once saw a call for proposals (from a certain three-letter agency) for a man-portable device that could extract a week's worth of potable water from desert air of XX relative humidity.  The power source was a key issue, then as now.